# When I plug in power to my laptop, my graphics card stops working

Tags: graphics-card

I searched every setting in Windows 11.  I put settings such as I prefer Nvidia processor. Prefer maximum performance and many others.

I have frame drops all the time and FPS doesn't go above 30 when laptop plugged in.

But when I'm on *battery*, my graphics card and the CPU graphics are running perfectly together!

Just to understand the problem, my battery runs out in 30 minutes.

I tried uninstalling the CPU graphics because I thought there was a problem between CPU and GPU. I installed them again.

If anyone has a solution it would be appreciated.

Comment: Try updating BIOS and Power Management Drivers (Manufacturer's driver update App). Restart when done and test.

Comment: Adding the make and model of device could assist in troubleshooting.  Also, anything in the Windows event logs that may help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the [Windows Power Plan options](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-custom-power-plans-windows-10) and set it on high performance or make your own custom power plan.
   **Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options**
2. If you have an NVIDIA GPU, Access the NVIDIA control panel when the laptop is plugged in, then you can select the preferred graphic processor.